# How to limit the use of a certain CPU to a certain group of users?

Tags: bash, scripting, debian, system-administration, cgroups

I'm using Debian.

In bash scripting I implemented a script that adds different users to the system obtaining data from file.

This data include a **primary group** and the **number of CPU that this group can use**. Data from users also can include several secondary groups and the CPU number each group is limited to.

I only need to apply the CPU limitation of the primary group, but I need to consider the limitation of secondary groups if the user changes its group to another.

In example: user John and Laura are in primary group RegularPeople which can only use CPU 2 and are also in secondary group VIP which can use CPU 0. This means that every process created by Laura and John should be executed by CPU 2. But, if John changes its primary group to VIPeople, processes created by John should be executing in CPU 0.

I know that I can do this with the utility cgroups, but could someone explain how to do that? I only know how to limit the CPU of a certain process by its ID, but this is out of my reach.

I've been programming in bash linux for several years, so writing code is not a problem, but I don't have any idea on how to solve this.

Thank you everyone for your help!